# Encoding error \xe9 and SQLite

Tags: python

I have this script to print my username, fullname and city from my skype account.
I have a problem when the city is composed with 'é' (or '\xe9') character. And my city is with that char. **I looked up arround UTF-8 but it does not help for 'é', 'è' chars. I need to convert these to normal 'e'.**

```
con = sqlite3.connect(path + '\\' + username + '\main.db')
with con:
    cur  = con.cursor()
    datapro = cur.execute("SELECT fullname,skypename,city, FROM Accounts;")
for row in datapro:
    details = {
            '[+] User ' : str(row[0]),
            '[+] Skype Username ' : str(row[1]),
            '[+] City ' : str(row[2]) or "unknown"
    }   
for i in details:
    data += i + '\t' + ': ' + details[i] + '\n'
```

I get an error : 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
Sorry if I did duplicate something but I didn't see my answer anywhere.
The result must become from 'Guérande' (error so not working) to 'Guerande' (here I think there is a way)
Thanks

Comment: Where Guérande is the city.

Comment: try `[+] City ' : row[2].encode("utf8") if row[2] else "unknown"`

Comment: Now I'm getting that error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 266: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to drop all the non ascii char et map them to the ascii closest version of it, you should try the `unidecode` package:

```
>>>from unidecode import unidecode
>>>unidecode("À Guérande on ramasse plutôt du sel")
'A Guerande on ramasse plutot du sel'
```

But to keep the accent you should try what is suggested in comment by Joran using `.encode('utf8')`.

Comment: Where does I place unidecode in the script I gave please?

Comment: You should place it around any string that may contain a special char, in your case, instead of `'[+] City ': str(row[2]) or "unknown"` you should put `'[+] City ' : unidecode(row[2]) or "unknown"`